# Deep linking - getInitialURL and subscribe not being called

Tags: react-native

**Current Behavior**

Currently trying to get getInitialURL and subscribe to work, but they are just no tbeing called

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {DefaultTheme, NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthStack from '../features/auth/AuthStack';
import {navigationRef} from './RootNavigation';
import {gestureHandlerRootHOC} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import {Linking} from 'react-native';

const Navigation = () => {


    const routeNameRef = React.useRef();
    const MyTheme = {
        ...DefaultTheme,
        colors: {
            ...DefaultTheme.colors,
            background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        },
    };
    const deepLinksConf = {
        initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
        screens: {
            Dashboard: {
                initialRouteName: 'Tasks',
                screens: {
                    Tasks: {
                        initialRouteName: 'TasksIndex',
                        screens: {
                            TasksIndex: 'TasksIndex',
                            TaskView: 'TaskView/:id',
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            queue: 'queue',
        },
    };

    const linking = {
        prefixes: ['verbleif://'],
        config: deepLinksConf,
        async getInitialURL() {
            console.log('getInitialURL');
            // Check if app was opened from a deep link
            const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
            console.log('just initial');
            if (url != null) {
                return url;
            }

            // Check if there is an initial firebase notification
            const message = await messaging().getInitialNotification();
            console.log('using firebase message link');

            // Get deep link from data
            // if this is undefined, the app will open the default/home page
            return message?.data?.llink;
        },
        subscribe(listener) {
            console.log('subscirbe');
            const onReceiveURL = ({url}: { url: string }) => listener(url);

            // Listen to incoming links from  deep linking
            Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);

            // Listen to firebase push notifications
            const unsubscribeNotification = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(
                (message) => {
                    console.log('onNotificationOpenedApp', message);
                    const url = message?.data?.link;

                    if (url) {
                        // Any custom logic to check whether the URL needs to be handled

                        // Call the listener to let React Navigation handle the URL
                        listener(url);
                    }
                },
            );

            return () => {
                // Clean up the event listeners
                Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
                unsubscribeNotification();
            };
        },

    };

    return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={linking} theme={MyTheme} ref={navigationRef}
                             // onReady={() => routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name}
                             // onStateChange={async () => {
                             //     const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
                             //     const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;
                             //
                             //     if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
                             //         // The line below uses the expo-firebase-analytics tracker
                             //         // https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/
                             //         // Change this line to use another Mobile analytics SDK
                             //         await analytics().logScreenView({
                             //             screen_name: currentRouteName,
                             //             screen_class: currentRouteName,
                             //         });
                             //     }
                             //
                             //     // Save the current route name for later comparision
                             //     routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
                             // }}
        >
            <AuthStack/>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default gestureHandlerRootHOC(Navigation);
```

**Expected Behavior**
The console logs to aleast appear

**How to reproduce**
Use the code above with the newest packages.
Your Environment

I am using react native CLI and just updated everything to newest